# Laravel Blade Not Rendering/ Layout Not Working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

So I created a custom layout for my design, it works on other blade but not for this one blade. I did some recheck just to make sure that it is the same as other blade that works.
Also the controller is prettymuch the same since it has the same function for my other blade.

**My checkout.blade :**

```
@extends('layouts.custom')
@section('content')
    <h1> Content </h1>
@endsection
```

**My custom layout**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        @yield('content')
    </body>
    <footer>
    </footer>
</html>
```

**My Controller:**

```
public function checkout()
    {
        $keranjangItems = \Cart::session(auth()->id())->getContent();

        return view('keranjang.checkout', compact('keranjangItems'));
    }
```

And I've tried to put the content on other blade and got no problem.
And I've tried to change my other controller to view this blade and also working.
Can anyone help me find where the problem is? thanks
Update: I also tried to just put together the code no include layout or what so ever and it's still have the same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your **custom.blade** file it says

```
@yield('layouts.header')
```

and on your **checkout.blade** file it says

```
@section('content')
    <h1> Content </h1>
@endsection
```

Either update the layout to match the section name on your checkout view or update the checkout view to match the yielded section name on the layout.

Comment: hi! thanks for your respond. sorry I got things in my head and I typed it 'layouts.header' instead of 'content' in the question section. but yeah I already match the name in my code tho

Comment: Ah! I see. Are you facing any error or just a white page?

Comment: white page, it's like it's not loading any css files.

Comment: To be honest, your situation is a bit hard to understand from distance. If you have your code hosted somewhere like github or gitlab, consider sharing the link.

Comment: yeah I already back up my project to my github, feel free to check it out. https://github.com/B1nz/Pasar